# Varying results from the Round function

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

My problem is simple. Consider the following.

```
a = {15, 15.01, 3, 3.01}
(* Out: {15, 15.01, 3, 3.01} *)

Mean[a]
(* Out: 9.005 *)

a - Mean[a]
(* Out: {5.995, 6.005, -6.005, -5.995} *)

Abs[a - Mean[a]]
(* Out: {5.995, 6.005, 6.005, 5.995} *)

Round[%, 0.01] 
(* Out: {6., 6.01, 6., 5.99} *)
```

As you can see, the values returned by `Round[6.005, 0.01]` vary: either $6.01$ or $6$ where the argument list shows $6.005$. The case where the argument list shows $5.995$ has a similar problem. I expected `{6., 6.01, 6.01, 6.}`.

Why does this occur, and how can I get a *right* answer?

## Update

I misunderstood [belisarius’ comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91819/round-function-s-result-is-various#comment249537_91819). He has explained why.

I thank to [MacroB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob) for his answer.

However, the question concerning how to get the result I expected is not yet answered.

Comment: try `Abs[a - Mean[a]] // FullForm` and you'll see ...

Comment: do you still have a question?  Note besides the floating point issue, `Round` rounds an exact .5 to the nearest even value, so the *right* answer one might expect mathematically here is `{6.,6.,6.,6.}`

Answer (score 3):

`FullForm` seems to be working fine here. Here is what [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) alluded to in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91819/round-function-s-result-is-various#comment249537_91819), using your definitions and either `InputForm`, or `FullForm` as he suggested:

```
InputForm@Abs[a - Mean[a]]
FullForm@Abs[a - Mean[a]]

(* Out from InputForm:
{5.995000000000001, 6.005000000000001, 6.004999999999999, 5.994999999999999}

Out from FullForm:
List[5.995000000000001`,6.005000000000001`,6.004999999999999`,5.994999999999999`]
*)
```

As you can see, the first and last numbers are in fact different in a subtle way, and they will end up being rounded differently by `Round`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the second part of your question is that you need to abandon machine precision arithmetic.

Perhaps the best way to proceed is use *Mathematica*'s exact arithmetic.

```
a = Rationalize @ {15., 15.01, 3., 3.01}
Round[Abs[a - Mean[a]], 1/100]
```

> ```
> {6, 6, 6, 6}
> ```

You could also use *Mathematica*'s slower but more accurate arbitrary precision arithmetic.

```
a = {15.`25, 15.01`25, 3.`25, 3.01`25};
Round[Abs[a - Mean[a]], 0.01`22]
```

> ```
> {6.000000000000000000000, 6.000000000000000000000, 
>  6.000000000000000000000, 6.000000000000000000000
> ```

If you are wondering why all the numbers get rounded to 6, it is because of the even-odd rule -- rounding down occurs when 5000... is to the right of an even digit and rounding up occurs when it to the right of an odd one; e.g.,

```
Round[{5.5, 6.5}]
```

> ```
> {6, 6}
> ```